# Cannot find module '@chakra-ui/react' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to install `@chakra-ui` and use it with Next, but it doesn't work at all. I uninstalled and installed it again and it doesn't work.

I used `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6`
didn't show any error on installation, but when I go to use `import {} from '@chakra-ui/react'` it just doesn't work, it says:

> Cannot find module '@chakra-ui/react' or its corresponding type
> declarations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sometimes it happens due to a TS server error. So ideally click ctrl+shift+p (Windows) and select the option "restart ts server". Had this issue many times and usually fixed import issues.

Answer (score 3):

I also tried uninstalling/reinstalling and it didn't appear to fix the issue until I restarted my development environment. Not sure which one actually fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling chakra ui fixed this for me.

```
npm uninstall i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by uninstalling then re-installing chakra-ui. Try this:

```
npm uninstall @chakra-ui/react
```

then re-install:

```
npm install @chakra-ui/react
```

Comment: This worked for me - any idea why it doesn't get picked up initially (i.e. why the reinstall is necessary) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2:
"@chakra-ui/icon": "^3.0.16",
"@chakra-ui/icon**s**": "^2.0.17",

check which one u need

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the type in the `-env.ts` file

`declare module "@chakra-ui/react"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Check the working directory: Ensure that the terminal is in the correct working directory where your project is located. You can use the `cd` command to navigate to the project directory in the terminal.

Then if the error still shows,
add `declare module "@chakra-ui/react";` to your -env.d.ts file